# How to change the background color of nth div

Tags: html, css

I need to change the background color of 1st, every 4th & every 5th div with class `cover-inner`

I tried following but it is not working

```
.cover-wrapper .cover-inner:nth-of-type(4n+4) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.cover-wrapper .cover-inner:nth-of-type(4n+5) {
     background-color: orange;
}
```

Actual  fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gfLPG/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put `nth-of-type()` on `.cover-wrapper` :

```
.cover-wrapper:nth-of-type(4n+4) .cover-inner {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.cover-wrapper:nth-of-type(4n+5) .cover-inner {
     background-color: orange;
}
```

As every `.cover-inner` is the only child of its parent, you will never catch'em.

---

Side notes:

- Use `:nth-of-type(4n)` instead of `:nth-of-type(4n+4)`
- Use `:nth-of-type(5n)` if you want to change color of every 5th elements (currently, you're changing the color of every 4th+1 element)
- Use `:nth-of-type(1)` or `:first-of-type()` to target the first element

Comment: Thanks, How ill i change the background color first div

Comment: With `.cover-wrapper:first-of-type() .cover-inner`

Comment: Did that `.cover-wrapper:nth-of-type(1) .cover-inner {
    background-color: red;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Try it :-

```
.cover-wrapper:nth-of-type(4n+4) .cover-inner {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.cover-wrapper:nth-of-type(4n+5) .cover-inner {
     background-color: orange;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_MukulKant/gfLPG/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

.cover-wrapper is having only one child. So there is no meaning to for giving nth child inside of .cover-wrapper with .cover-inner class.

instead of it you can use :nth-child with .cover-wrapper

```css
.cover-wrapper{height:20px; width:200px; background-color:blue;margin:10px;}
   .cover-wrapper:first-child .cover-inner {
       background-color: green;
   }
   .cover-wrapper:nth-of-type(4n+4) .cover-inner {
       background-color: yellow;
   }
   .cover-wrapper:nth-of-type(4n+5) .cover-inner {
        background-color: orange;
   }
```

```html
<div class="cover-wrapper"><div class="cover-inner"><div>Image Item</div></div></div>
    <div class="cover-wrapper"><div class="cover-inner"><div>Image Item</div></div></div>
    <div class="cover-wrapper"><div class="cover-inner"><div>Image Item</div></div></div>
    <div class="cover-wrapper"><div class="cover-inner"><div>Image Item</div></div></div>
    
    <div class="cover-wrapper"><div class="cover-inner"><div>Image Item</div></div></div>
    <div class="cover-wrapper"><div class="cover-inner"><div>Image Item</div></div></div>
    <div class="cover-wrapper"><div class="cover-inner"><div>Image Item</div></div></div>
    <div class="cover-wrapper"><div class="cover-inner"><div>Image Item</div></div></div>
    
    <div class="cover-wrapper"><div class="cover-inner"><div>Image Item</div></div></div>
    <div class="cover-wrapper"><div class="cover-inner"><div>Image Item</div></div></div>
    <div class="cover-wrapper"><div class="cover-inner"><div>Image Item</div></div></div>
    <div class="cover-wrapper"><div class="cover-inner"><div>Image Item</div></div></div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
```